# How to perform only "Distinct Root" but not generating distinct in result SQL for JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am now using Spring Data JPA + Hibernate for my data access layer.

Assuming I have entity `A`, which is having One-To-May relationship to `B`.

When I am trying to query for `A` join fetching `B`, my first trial is like this:

```
from A a join fetch a.b
```

However, because `A.b` is one to many, for the way JPA and Hibernate works, the result `List<A>` will contain multiple element pointing to same A instance (because each element in the result list will correspond to one row in result set).

The way to solve is by writing

```
select distinct a from A a join fetch a.b
```

From my understanding, this is going to cause two effects:

1. Result SQL will contains `distinct` keyword
2. JPA/Hibernate will do a "Distinct Root" transformation when constructing the result list.

I would want to know if there is any way that I only have point 2 (Distinct Root) in effect (because distinct in result SQL is not necessary in my case, and it is causing performance problem), preferably a JPA-based solution?

Further more, is there something I can do on Spring Data to achieve what I am looking for?  (e.g. Any `@QueryHint` or special JPQL/HQL syntax that I can use?)

(I know some workaround like making the result a `Set<A>` but I would want to use it as the last resort if I cannot find any solution provided by JPA/Hibernate for such scenario)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Why are you fetch joining B?

Comment: @Pace I don't know which part of my intention is unclear: I am trying to do join fetching for related entities, for which should be something quite common in JPA/Hibernate

Comment: If your goal is performance another thing you can try is issuing two queries.  One to select the A's and one to select the B's.  Depending on how many rows you have this can be more performance as the copies of A don't have to be sent across the wire.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used

```
session.createQuery("...")
   .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITIY)
   .list();
```